# AutoFilter return correct result, but when SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).value , excel only return half of the record

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

this is my code

```
openWs.AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
">=" & date1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & date2
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, VisibleDropDown:=False
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=5, VisibleDropDown:=False
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, VisibleDropDown:=False
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=7, VisibleDropDown:=False
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=8, VisibleDropDown:=False
cnt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
arr() = openWs.Range("A2:H" & cnt).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value 'Supplier
```

The AutoFilter had show that I had 40 record, but when using .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), I just get about 20 record from it, after check through the record, I figure out that it always return the last range that match with date2, data after the range will just ignore, why?

//sample data after filter

filter range 20130101 - 20130107

```
20130104    7339/01/13  13006015    CN  -250000 -639442350.6  //Success
20130107    7346/01/13  13002022    DN  1200000 -639442350.6 //Success
//data below all ignore after hitting 20130107, only return data above target
20130104    7340/01/13  13006016    CN  -300000 118968559.6 //Failed
20130107    7340/01/13  13006016    CN  -300000 118968559.6 //Failed
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I thought excel will automatically return everything that visible after the filter, but it seems like it still apply the same filter? Any idea?

**Update 1**
More sample data, after apply Siddharth Rout code

```
CP0001  20130103    I/TAX - 12TH INST YA2012    13012000    PR  -180000 0
CP0001  20130103    I/TAX - 12TH INST YA2012    13014000    PPR 180000  0
HH2000  20130102    7324/01/13  13006000    CN  -100000 -639442350.6
HH2000  20130102    7325/01/13  13002001    DN  1500000 -639442350.6
HH2000  20130103    7326/01/13  13006002    CN  -17000000   -639442350.6
HH2000  20130103    7348/01/13  13006024    CN  -3000000    -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7327/01/13  13006003    CN  -10000000   -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7328/01/13  13006004    CN  -10000000   -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7329/01/13  13006005    CN  -500000 -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7330/01/13  13006006    CN  -1500000    -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7331/01/13  13006007    CN  -1000000    -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7332/01/13  13006008    CN  -3000000    -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7333/01/13  13006009    CN  -135000 -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7334/01/13  13006010    CN  -5000000    -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7335/01/13  13006011    CN  -31099000   -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7336/01/13  13006012    CN  -7000   -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7337/01/13  13006013    CN  -5000   -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7338/01/13  13006014    CN  -700000 -639442350.6
HH2000  20130104    7339/01/13  13006015    CN  -250000 -639442350.6
HH2000  20130107    7341/01/13  13006017    CN  -4563000    -639442350.6
HH2000  20130107    7343/01/13  13006019    CN  -1800000    -639442350.6
HH2000  20130107    7344/01/13  13002020    DN  800000  -639442350.6
HH2000  20130107    7345/01/13  13002021    DN  900000  -639442350.6
HH2000  20130107    7346/01/13  13002022    DN  1200000 -639442350.6 //it stop here, below all ignore by excel
HH2030  20130104    7338/01/13  13002014    DN  700000  5318670.54
HH2100  20130104    7340/01/13  13006016    CN  -300000 118968559.6
HH2100  20130107    7342/01/13  13006018    CN  -980000 118968559.6
HH2101  20130107    7347/01/13  13006023    CN  -300000 -12587577.27
```

Comment: just quick idea- possibly data in column 1 is not recognised as date value?...

Comment: izzit I already start at openWs.Range("A2:H" & cnt)? the excel autofilter correctly, but vba just stop get to next row after found date2

Comment: `Range("A1").AutoFilter`? Shouldn't it be `Range("A1:H" & cnt).AutoFilter Field:=...`

Comment: The autofilter work well ever with just A1, no idea why, the only problem come from is the arr() did not store complete filtered data, it just stop at whatever data that match the date2, after that it wont continue to read next row

Comment: `The autofilter work well ever with just A1` Insert a blank row or few blank rows between your data. Does it still work? BTW you keep on mentioning `20130107` as a date. This is not a valid date. It is simply a number. Until and unless you actually have a date which is formatted as `yyyymmdd` or `yyyyddmm`

Comment: yeah sorry for that, it is not formatted date, a string, which will be formatted after assigned to array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my comments, try this. This works for me.

**EDIT**: Just so that there is no confusion, what @mehow mentioned below is absolutely correct. The below is just a sample data. When you are actually working with data where you have to apply autofilter, use headers in 1st row and then use `.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to get the filtered data as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s)

**Code:**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim openWs As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, VisbRange As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, date1  as Long, date2 as Long
    Set openWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    date1 = 20130101
    date2 = 20130107

    With openWs
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        Set rng = .Range("A1:H" & lRow)

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With rng

            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
            ">=" & date1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & date2

            .AutoFilter Field:=4, VisibleDropDown:=False
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, VisibleDropDown:=False
            .AutoFilter Field:=6, VisibleDropDown:=False
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, VisibleDropDown:=False
            .AutoFilter Field:=8, VisibleDropDown:=False

            Set VisbRange = .Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            Debug.Print VisbRange.Address
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**ScreenShots: (Before After)**

[image]

**Followup form comments**:

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim openWs As Worksheet, tmpSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, VisbRange As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, date1  As Long, date2 As Long
    Dim Arr

    Set openWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    date1 = 20130101
    date2 = 20130107

    With openWs
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        Set rng = .Range("A1:F" & lRow)

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With rng

            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
            ">=" & date1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & date2

            .AutoFilter Field:=4, VisibleDropDown:=False
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, VisibleDropDown:=False
            .AutoFilter Field:=6, VisibleDropDown:=False

            Set VisbRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow

            Set tmpSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

            VisbRange.Copy tmpSheet.Rows(1)

            With tmpSheet
                lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                Arr = .Range("A1:H" & lRow).Value
            End With

            On Error Resume Next
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            tmpSheet.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for tackling this but doesn't applying autofilter to the header eliminate the header from being filtered?

Comment: What you are saying is absolutely correct and hence one should always have a header when applying autofilter. I just created an example to demonstrate why is it important to define the complete range before setting an autofilter on a range.

Comment: and congrats on 40K! that's amazing

Comment: For example in [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) thread which demonstrate on how to use `.OFFSET` to work with headers

Comment: it still the same, it just stop to get to next row after hitting date at 20130107, I did have a header at the 1st row, did it cause the problem?

Comment: @Se0ng11: May I see your excel file? You can upload it in any free file sharing site and share the link here.

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/463401/sample-zip.html, not sure where to upload, i had uploaded here

Comment: @Se0ng11: Just checked it. It works for me. Returns 52 records in Autofilter.

Comment: Set VisbRange = .Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            arr() = VisbRange.Value

it return? why I cant? in excel, the auto filter show 52 record, but before assign into array, it just return 24, arrr, it killing me

Comment: @Se0ng11: Ah I see what you are trying. You can't store non contiguous ranges like this in the array. If you do then it will store the values from the first Area of the range which is 24 in your case. Let me show you an alternative on how to achieve what you want.

Comment: Nope ;) Refresh the page after exactly 30 seconds and see the updated solution.

Comment: Unbelievable, it works,  need to study more on this non contiguous thing, I thought just a simple few line is enough to cater that, but in the end, thanks Siddharth, your code teach me a lot, thanjs