# VBA Excel to select range only if current date is there

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compile a code that will get the data from every sheet in a workbook that is titled Employee- and pull the data that only has the current date in Column "O" however I am having issues adding criteria field and I'm probably just not doing it correctly.

```
Sub x()

    Dim NewWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim r As Excel.Range
    Dim r2 As Excel.Range

    Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(6).Range("B1:O1").Copy NewWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.name Like "Employee*" Then

        Set r = ws.Range("B2", ws.Range("O" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.count) Field:=15, Criteria1:=">=" & Date)

        r.Copy

        Set r2 = NewWB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        r2.Offset(, 14).Resize(r.Rows.count).Value = ws.name
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use AutoFilter, but we can only use it to organize the data before copying it.  The info here is really useful: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba.htm.  Then we need to set the range to the newly filtered range before copying:

```
Sub x()

Dim NewWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim r2 As Excel.Range

Set NewWB = Workbooks.Add

'Not sure what this is for or if you need this
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(6).Range("B1:O1").Copy NewWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name Like "Employee*" Then

        ws.AutoFilterMode = False

        Dim filterRange As Excel.Range

        Set filterRange = ws.Range("B2", ws.Range("O" & ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count))

        filterRange.AutoFilter
        filterRange.AutoFilter _
            Field:=14, _
            Criteria1:=">=" & Date

        'Set to the cells that aren't filtered out
        Set r = filterRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 

        r.Copy

        Set r2 = NewWB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        r2.Offset(, 14).Resize(r.Rows.Count).Value = ws.Name

        ws.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove filter after you're done

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

EDIT:  We were on the wrong track.  AutoFilter doesn't return a range, it sets an AutoFilter to a range.  Sorry about leading you astray, the only place I've seen "Field:" and "Criteria1:" used is for AutoFilter.  But I see how it's used here, [AutoFilter Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521105/autofilter-return-correct-result-but-when-specialcellsxlcelltypevisible-value), and revised my post to what I think will do the trick.

EDIT: Found the bug.  There aren't 15 fields in our filtered range.  Just 14.  Added full Sub to answer.

Comment: I'm getting a compile error: Expected: expression on the line that has Field:=15,_ I tried just deleting the code separator and having the field next to the .AutoFilter but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Lilly Let me know if the edit I made to this answer doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that what you wrote would work, but the issue I'm having is that the filter part is set in the code you provided is for the new workbook that was being added, therefore an error is occuring because the data hasn't copied over yet.

Comment: @Lilly We were going wrong with trying to set the filter criteria to a column that wasn't within the filter (there are only 14 columns because we skipped the first one).  The new edit to the answer should work for you.

Comment: That did the trick, but now when pasting it's pasting over the previously pasted data. It's not pasting on the next available row.

Comment: @Lilly, I'm trying it out with some random data and the only way I'm seeing the problem is if the first column is empty.  You could try using this: 
    Set r2 = NewWB.Sheets(1).Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -13)